# How to send message between two android devices via the internet

Tags: java, android, server

I need to develop an app that transfers data between two different devices.
For example I need to build a chat application that send messages between two devices that sit in different geographic area.(via internet connection !)
**Device A** know the IP of **Device B** and via versa.
I know that the IP I received in my devices are under the ISP.

I have some questions :

1. Is there any solution for that issue without connection server in the middle, sending messages/data between different devices (without any third party component).
2. If the answer for question 1 is NO! (or it's very difficult for implementation) . May you suggest a way to implement with a server in the middle (how to keep the channel open ?). Do the server need to keep the sockets of the two devices open all the time? , or maybe the connection can be made by demand (how application like whatsapp work?).

Comment: Android devices use sockets just like servers...

Comment: check this out: [Tutorial to build Chat using Firebase](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/)

Comment: For question 1: yes. You need a server app and a client app. The server app device should use wifi connection. The client app can use both mobile and wifi connection. The third party component is at least a router with wifi.

Comment: @greenapps Why would Wifi be required? Assuming we have an internet connection (Which isn't even required if they're on the same network), it's just a matter of connecting the devices with sockets.

Comment: First read the question. It states using internet. Second if they were on the same network they both would use wifi. So your question is not to the point. Please rephrase.